# esbuild.js's "watch" gives error "Failed to write to output file:..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, esbuild

I'm using "esbuild 0.17.14" with a a config file named "esbuild.config.js" which contains the script you can see below. After a couple of changes in the file that esbuild watches and bundles, I get the error you can see in the screenshot. This happens every time. That means that if I get the error, then stop the esbuild 'watch' and rebuild then the rebuild is going to work without problems. So, it's not some issue in my code I guess. At the same time, I am using VS code's extension "Live Server" if that is relevant to the problem somehow.

[esbuild fail error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkTet.png)

***Failed to write to output file: open D:\Users\anonymized_path\dist\page.js: The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.***

```
// fileName: esbuild.config.js

import esbuild from "esbuild";
import glob from "glob";

const context = await esbuild.context({
    entryPoints: glob.sync("src/*.js"),
    bundle: true,
    minify: true,
    sourcemap: false,
    outdir: "dist",
    format: "esm",
    splitting: false,
    metafile: true,
    // loader: {
    //   ".png": "file",
    //   ".svg": "file",
    // },
    write: true,
    logLevel: "info",
  })
  .catch(() => process.exit(1));

  await context.watch()
```

I'have tried to close all the open files, close the browser, close live server, delete the output files. Nothing worked and I don't really know what else to try.